# How many xml http requests is too much for a pc to handle?

Tags: apache-2.2, mediawiki

I'm running mediawiki on an apache on a regular pc running vista (don't know the specific specs, but I'm guessing at least duo core 2 2 giga hertz processor, broadband connection (500 kb/s at least, probably 1 mega).

I want to use the MediaWiki api to send a lot of requests to this server. Most of the time the requests will be sent through LAN (but sometimes through the internet). I'm talking thousands of requests every few seconds at worst case. (A lot of these requests may repeat themselves, I guess some sort of cache would help)

Will the server handle this, or do I need a stronger/dedicated computer?
(I'm not looking for specific yes/no, but just want to get an idea as to what configuration of computer will support how many request per second)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try it.  The only way to know for sure what your equipment can do, especially without knowing the specifications, is to benchmark it.

Comment: I'm guessing that there are people who know from their experience how many simultaneous users this kind of pc can support... again, not looking for an exact number, but orders of magnitude.

Answer (score 0):

That machine is fast enough to easily saturate a 100MB ethernet link which is probably what is being used to connect to the router/modem (all the best zombie networks have many just like it). The ultimate limiting factor, apart from network speed, is going to be disk IO and the software itself.

Keep in mind that an ordinary broadband connection has different upstream and downstream speeds. So you'll hit the ceiling on the lower upstream speed limit before you hit disk IO and software limits.

Also, Vista is not really tuned for server duty. I believe Windows Server 2008 is the server edition of Vista ... if there even is one.

The only real test is to try it. It probably will be good enough.